# Xcode Swift auto-complete shows wrong method

Tags: xcode, swift, generics, subclass, type-alias

I have the following classes:

```
class FooClass<A,B>: NSObject {

    func foo(a: A, b: B) { } 

}

class BarClass: FooClass<Int, Bool> { 

    override func foo(a: A, b: B) { }        //AUTO-COMPLETE'S PREVIEW SHOWS THIS, BUT COMPILER COMPLAINS "USE OF UNDECLARED TYPE 'A'"

    override func foo(a: Int, b: Bool) { }   //AUTO-COMPLETE'S PREVIEW DOESN'T SHOW THIS, BUT COMPILER APPROVES

}
```

The auto-complete preview shows the wrong one, because the compiler doesn't like it. Am I declaring one of my classes incorrectly, or does the auto-complete need to be fixed?

Comment: Seems like a bug with auto-complete...

Comment: If compiler gives you an error then yes, you declared `BarClass` incorrectly. I tested your code in Xcode 7 playground and auto-complete shows me `foo(a: Int, b: Bool)`.

Comment: @mixel can you give an answer showing a screen shot? My experience reproduces the OP's claim exactly. I'd like to see your counterexample.

Comment: @matt I gave an answer. I hope that I correctly understood OP's claim.

Comment: I'd say file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @matt for explanation of OP's issue.

Auto-complete must show `foo(a: Int, b: Bool)` when you override `FooClass.foo` in `BarClass` but it shows `foo(a: A, b: B)` which seems like a bug:
[image: Screenshot of bug]

Also when you do not override `FooClass.foo` in `BarClass` and call it like `BarClass().foo` auto-complete is also wrong:
[image]

But if you override `FooClass.foo` in `BarClass` then auto-complete is correct:
[image]

Comment: But I think the OP is talking about the auto-complete when _declaring_ `foo` back in the BarClass _definition_, not when _calling_ foo later. The point is that since only the second declaration is legal, that is the one that auto-complete should have offered. But instead it offered the first one, which is illegal.

Comment: Thanks for your work @mixel. @matt is correct in saying that I was having auto-complete problems when overriding `foo` in the BarClass definition. I think the reason it's working for you there is because you already have the override correctly defined.

I have one more question, if you don't mind. If I don't override `foo`, should i expect `BarClass().foo` to show the auto-complete with `foo(a: A, b: B)` or `foo(a: Int, b: Bool)`? I'll be glad to accept your answer @mixel if you would like to update it to reflect the current understanding of the issue. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @mixel! I'll file a bug report.